# How to access a member of a class which is inside another object from JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON String like this

```
$test='{"var1":null,"var3":null,"status":{"code":150,"message":"blah blah"}}';
```

I want to access the status code in the function.
this is what i tried:

```
$responseObj=jsonService->decode($test);//this converts the string into an Object

echo $responseObj->status->code;
```

now this isnt working. Can someone point me in the right direction. I think that

```
$responseObj->status->code
```

is the wrong syntax to use. What is the right syntax.
I am using PHP 5.1.6 , this doesnt have the inbuilt json_decode function. So I am using a third party Class to convert. I use the following third party class

- @package     Services_JSON
- @author      Michal Migurski
- @author      Matt Knapp
- @author      Brett Stimmerman
- @copyright   2005 Michal Migurski
- @version     CVS: $Id: JSON.php,v 1.31 2006/06/28 05:54:17 migurski Exp $
- @license     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
- @link        http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198

Comment: you sure it returns an object? not an associative array? tried `$responseObj['status']['code']` yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give PHP's json_decode() a try:

```
$test='{"var1":null,"var3":null,"status":{"code":150,"message":"blah blah"}}';
$responseObj = json_decode($test);
echo $responseObj->status->code;
```

For PEARS's Services_JSON Class ([Documentation](http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/doc/)):

```
// create a new instance of Services_JSON
$jsonService = new Services_JSON();

$test='{"var1":null,"var3":null,"status":{"code":150,"message":"blah blah"}}';
$jsonService->decode($test);
echo $responseObj->status->code;
```

Comment: @blockhead,@kelix,@crem0r: json_decode is a fairly new function. It isnt available on PHP 5.1.6 so have to use a third party class for the JSON decode and encode.

Comment: Well can you tell us the library you are using and any errors that come up? You're syntax is now correct from what I can see so it's likely something internal.

Comment: i have edited the question to include the name of the package and other details about the class.

Comment: If your host is still using PHP 5.1.6 you might have bigger problems!

Comment: Try swapping 'echo $responseObj->status->code;' for 'echo var_dump($responseObj);' to see if there are any contents returned.

Comment: @Kelix: var_dump dont need to be echoed. It outputs its result directly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for this task.  Also, your input string should have quotes:

```
$test='{"var1":null,"var3":null,"status":{"code":150,"message":"blah blah"}}';

$responseObj = json_decode($test);

echo $responseObj->status->code;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're jsonService is doing but this worked for me:

```
$json = '{"var1":null,"var3":null,"status":{"code":150,"message":"blah blah"}}';

$result = json_decode($json);

echo $result->status->code;
```